# Can't unfocus button onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<button onClick={()=>{
    console.log(document.activeElement);
    this.searchWindowRef.targetRef?.focus();
    console.log(this.targetRef.current);
    console.log(document.activeElement);
}}/>
```

Prints

```html
<button/>
<target/>
<button/>
```

Obviously, the expected result is

```html
<button/>
<target/>
<target/>
```